# AWS MSK Kafka producer gives error - Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: java.io.IOException: Too many open files

Tags: java, apache-kafka, aws-lambda, aws-msk

I am writing a lambda that would publish events on kafka. So lambda has logic for publishing kafka events.
Lambda concurrency level when set to high value, say 32, I get errors as -
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: java.io.IOException: Too many open files

Here is kafka producer setting -

```
kafkaProducerProperties.put(BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, 100000);
kafkaProducerProperties.put(LINGER_MS_CONFIG, "3000");
kafkaProducerProperties.put(MAX_BLOCK_MS_CONFIG, "5000");
kafkaProducerProperties.put("acks", "1");
```

These are the cluster settings -

```
auto.create.topics.enable=true
default.replication.factor=3
min.insync.replicas=2
num.io.threads=8
num.network.threads=5
num.partitions=1
num.replica.fetchers=2
replica.lag.time.max.ms=30000
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
unclean.leader.election.enable=true
zookeeper.session.timeout.ms=18000
```

I am not able to understand why kafka is erring out -

```
START RequestId: 3591b950-bdd7-45c4-8de8-c9ed9ca654bf Version: $LATEST
Failed to construct kafka producer: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:465)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:290)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:317)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:302)
at com.polestar.dependencies.Beans.getProducer(Beans.java:59)
at com.polestar.dependencies.Beans_GetProducerFactory.getProducer(Beans_GetProducerFactory.java:41)
at com.polestar.dependencies.Beans_GetProducerFactory.get(Beans_GetProducerFactory.java:33)
at com.polestar.dependencies.Beans_GetProducerFactory.get(Beans_GetProducerFactory.java:11)
at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
at com.polestar.dependencies.Beans_GetKafkaProducerFactory.get(Beans_GetKafkaProducerFactory.java:39)
at com.polestar.dependencies.Beans_GetKafkaProducerFactory.get(Beans_GetKafkaProducerFactory.java:13)
at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
at com.polestar.dependencies.Beans_GetAisFusingServiceFactory.get(Beans_GetAisFusingServiceFactory.java:44)
at com.polestar.dependencies.Beans_GetAisFusingServiceFactory.get(Beans_GetAisFusingServiceFactory.java:14)
at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
at com.polestar.dependencies.DaggerEventProcessorComponent$EventProcessorComponentImpl.injectAISFuserApplication(DaggerEventProcessorComponent.java:99)
at com.polestar.dependencies.DaggerEventProcessorComponent$EventProcessorComponentImpl.inject(DaggerEventProcessorComponent.java:93)
at com.polestar.AISFuserApplication.handleRequest(AISFuserApplication.java:30)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor84.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: java.io.IOException: Too many open files
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.<init>(Selector.java:161)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.<init>(Selector.java:212)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.<init>(Selector.java:224)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.<init>(Selector.java:228)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.newSender(KafkaProducer.java:515)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:454)
... 20 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Too many open files
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.makePipe(Native Method)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorProvider.openSelector(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.nio.channels.Selector.open(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.<init>(Selector.java:159)
... 25 more
```

How can this be resolved?

Comment: The error is from your producer client, not the brokers. Increase the file handles on the machine where your producer is running

Comment: My producer is running inside lambda.

Comment: Okay, then maybe contact AWS support since it is their infrastructure and see what they suggest? As mentioned, Kafka/MSK isn't the issue here

Answer (score 0):

As the comment on your post mentions, this is a client side producer error caused by too many open files or file descriptors.

As the producer client does not use any files, most likely this is related to a high number of connections and I would suspect in this case that you are creating too many KafkaProducer objects which will in turn create a connection per object and use a file handle.

One common mistake lambda developers make is to instantiate the producer in the handleRequest method instead of globally and I suspect that is maybe whats happening here or something similar.

To fix, ensure that you only have 1 instance of a producer by creating it globally as a singleton. e.g.

```
public class MyLambdaHandler implements RequestHandler<String, String> {

    // Define the Kafka producer outside the handler method.
    // Instantiate in the constructor.
    private final KafkaProducer<String, String> kafkaProducer;
```

Alternatively, if you need more than one producer then store in a HashMap or similar but either way add a mechanism to ensure you are not constantly instantiating new objects.

*Update following comment*: To validate the above theory I would recommend adding metrics and logging to measure the client side connection count from the lambda to MSK. If this is your only producer you can use the server side metric.

Comment: I am using dagger framework. I am creating KafkaProducerClient as a singleton bean. Wouldn't that ensure there is only one instance of kafka producer per lambda instance?

Comment: @SWAPSTG Does it work without Dagger? Maybe the issue is there?

Comment: Yes using a dep injection framework like dagger should solve this assuming its used correctly. Probably the next thing to do is validate this by emitting metrics to check the number of client side connections. I will update my answer to suggest this